Quick scroll view: cannot stop scroll action from drag gesture
I have a scrollable list with a quick scroll view in an overlay allowing to rapidly move down the list (simplified here to be concise).
It works as expected, and you can tap or drag on the quick scroll view to reach any position within the list.
But if the list was already scrolling before (due to a drag gesture on it), the scroll action from the quick scroll only takes place after the first scroll is done. This can take quite some time since there is substantial momentum in the scrolling process.
Can this somehow be avoided?
View:
struct ItemListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ItemViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List {
                ForEach(0..<200){ index in
                    Text("Item \(index)")
                        .id(String(index))
                }
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.visible)
            .overlay(ItemQuickScrollView(scroll: { pos in
                withAnimation {
                    proxy.scrollTo(viewModel.getQuickScrollTarget(pos))
                }
            }))
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}

ViewModel:
@MainActor public class ItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
     func getQuickScrollTarget(val: Double) -> String {
         return String(Int(200 * val))
     }
}

QuickScrollView:
struct ItemQuickScrollView: View {
    @State var value: Double = .zero
    var scroll: (Double) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.2)) // for debugging
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .frame(width: 40, height: geometry.size.height)
                    .padding(.trailing, -15)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                            .onChanged( { value in
                                self.scrollAction(value.location.y / geometry.size.height)
                            })
                    )
            }
        }
    }
    
    func scrollAction(_ val: Double) -> Void {
        let yRelative = min(1, max(0, val))
        self.scroll(yRelative)
    }
}

The best solution would be to somehow abort the first scroll action, or overwrite its target with a new one. But if that is possible it would at least be nice to somehow disable or reduce the momentum of the scroll action so that the delay is not so large.

If you could find a way to reduce the intertia of the scroll action then this might provide a workaround, because the scroll action would come to a stop sooner. One way would be to use a ScrollView + LazyVStack, instead of a List. You could then use .scrollTargetLayout and .scrollPosition, instead of a ScrollViewReader. Then, you could implement your own ScrollTargetBehavior, which could ignore the velocity of the inertia scroll. An example can be found in this answer.
